# How to avoid XCode debugger to step into std system headers?

Tags: c++, xcode, debugging

When using the "Step into" command in XCode debugger, how can I avoid it to step into the standard system headers?
This behaviour makes sense because it's a headers being compiled, but is a waste of time.
I never want to see what's happening inside the standard library, just my code.

Answer (score 0):

Not a permanent fix, but right to the left of the "step into" command is a "step over".

Not sure if there's a better way, but what I have been always doing is just switching to the step over button whenever I'm looking at Standard system functions.

Comment: It works when already inside, but won't avoid to get into it.